# What does "NODE_WITNESS (12)" mean as it is shown in bitnodes.21.co?

Tags: bitcoin-core, segregated-witness, pruning, node-services, bitnodes

I'm running a pruned full node of bitcoin core version 0.14.0 and checking on https://bitnodes.21.co/nodes/ I can see that my node was labelled "NODE_WITNESS (12)" unlike of the others nodes shown, which was labelled "NODE_WITNESS (13)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've looked through several pages on bitnodes to find some more nodes that show `NODE_WITNESS (12)`. I've noticed a pattern: the number corresponds to the services that a node offers. Nodes advertise the services that they offer by sending a bitmap named `nServices`. The number in the brackets matches the decimal representation of the service bits that a node has set.

Looking around a bit, I've identified the following five bits:

- `NODE_NETWORK (1)`
- `NODE_GETUTXO (2)`
- `NODE_BLOOM (4)`
- `NODE_WITNESS (8)`
- `NODE_XTHIN (16)`, discontinued
- `NODE_COMPACT_FILTERS  (64)`
- `NODE_NETWORK_LIMITED (1024)`

So, I'd say that with (12), you must be offering the services `NODE_BLOOM, NODE_WITNESS (12)`, lemme guess, you run a pruning node? :) Or would it be "blocksonly"?

---

Edit: Here are the service bits defined in the source code: [`protocol.h:271`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/a9f642870849dcbfe32632fd6614804be61ab40c/src/protocol.h#L271). And here is an overview in the Bitcoin Wiki page for [protocol documentation](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#version).

Comment: Yes, I'm running a pruning node!